# What's wrong with my remove cronjob php function?

Tags: php, shell, command, cron

I'm trying to write a function that helps with deleting cron jobs, I've tried some classes from the net but it didn't work, so I'm writing it myself ,the problem that it's not removing command correctly, it's either deleting it or it's removing half of every cron job that is exist in the file!

Here's my function :

```
function delete_cronjob($command)
{
   $outputs = array();
    exec('crontab -l',$outputs);

    for($i=0;$i<count($outputs);$i++)
    {
        if ($outputs[$i]==$command)
            $outputs[$i]=NULL;
    }

      shell_exec('crontab -r');
      for($i=0;$i<count($outputs);$i++)
      {
          if ($outputs[$i]!=NULL)
            shell_exec('(crontab -l ; echo "'.$outputs[$i].'") |uniq - | crontab -');
      }
```

}

And this is the kind of cron job I use :

```
$command='0 0 * * * ssh -p 22 root@192.168.0.121 "cd /home/sally/;./bckp_rstr.bash _ _ 0 1 test root@192.168.0.196:/home/sally/sal_bckp/ 192.168.0.121 22 1 "';
delete_cronjob($command);
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe try escaping `$outputs[$i]` with `escapeshellarg()` before you pass it to `shell_exec()`?

Comment: it didn't help . what is this ??

Comment: `$command` contains double quotes and it is wrapped with double quotes in the shell_exec() call. My guess was that this could cause some problems since the quotes weren't escaped.

Comment: try taking the `uniq` out of the picture and see if that changes things. Also, I think it will be easier if you save your re-written file to the /tmp dir and then just load the whole thing in at once. Then delete the tmp file. I don't see how having 2 `crontab` cmds in the same `system(...)` can work. Good luck.

Comment: Can you use file_get_contents and file_put_contents instead of those shell execs?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Actually I didn't try it ! :D

Comment: @shellter I will try your way also

Answer (score 0):

If it works on your system like it does on mine (Fedora) I would suggest just using file_put_contents, much less to go wrong

Also I store the cron jobs in a database, so I can flag them as active/inactive and just dump out the active ones - along with a field for comments/description of what it does

it has the downside of overwriting any crons edited manually, but I don't tend to do that. The advantage of having a store of crons that can be accessed by al our servers - there is a field that says which server(s) the crons are for - outweighs that. It also means the the list of crons is backed up along with the rest of the data, and can easily be pushed out to other machines if need be :) worth considering.